# WebRTC - Reduce streamed audio volume

Tags: webrtc, audio-streaming

Suppose we get an audio stream by using getUserMedia(gUM) API. I am broadcasting this stream to other users using WebRTC. 
  Is it possible to reduce the volume of the audio getting streamed.

Note : I am not looking to reduce device mic volume, because I understand we cannot control through browser and I dont want to

Answer (score 0):

Try with [GainNode](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/GainNode) from WebAudio. But the best thing will be to do this on the receiving end.

Comment: Will give this a try. Receiving end may be cumbersome for me to implement for the architecture I am using, will let you know.